# Green function for gradient

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Does a Green function for the gradient exist? Specifically, consider the equation $$\vec{\nabla}_x\, G(\vec{x},\vec{x}') = \vec{\delta}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}'),$$ where $\vec{\delta}(\vec{x}-\vec{x}')$ is some sort of a vector generalization of the standard scalar delta function. Have such equations been investigated? If so, how does one derive the Green function for the gradient operator?